# Updating deeply nested state in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm updating a "message board" project I did (Brad Traversy's MERN stack course) to include comment likes.  For a simple example, think Facebook: you create a post which people can like, and people can respond with comments, which can also be liked.

I have a "post" piece of state, which contains post likes (post.likes array), comments (post.comments array), and comment likes (where things get tricky: an array nested inside the post.comments array).

How do I update the nested arrays in my reducer so my page re-renders properly?  Right now, it records the action and shows the new likes/dislikes when the page reloads manually, but it won't reload the page itself.

I've tried updating the state, but the reality is, I'm not entirely sure how to loop through and update something deeply nested.

Here is my actual post state, courtesy of Redux DevTools.

```
post: {
    posts: [],
    post: {
      _id: '5cebd8bcdc17fd5cd7e57a45',
      text: 'This is my brand new post.',
      name: 'Bobby Smith',
      avatar: '//www.gravatar.com/avatar/414868368393e3ba8ae5ff93eeb98de6?s=200&r=pg&d=mm',
      user: '5cd646c9a632b51373121995',
      likes: [
        {
          _id: '5cebd8d1dc17fd5cd7e57a47',
          user: '5cd36ce5fda120050ee64160'
        }
      ],
      comments: [
        {
          date: '2019-05-27T12:32:16.172Z',
          likes: [ /*-------- This ---------*/
            {
              _id: '5cebd8e1dc17fd5cd7e57a48',
              user: '5cd646c9a632b51373121995'
            }
          ],
          _id: '5cebd8d0dc17fd5cd7e57a46',
          text: 'And this is my brand new response.',
          name: 'John Doe',
          avatar: '//www.gravatar.com/avatar/b2b146dba9e0023cb56637f0df4aa005?s=200&r=pg&d=mm',
          user: '5cd36ce5fda120050ee64160'
        }
      ],
      date: '2019-05-27T12:31:56.598Z',
      __v: 3
    },
    loading: false,
    error: {}
  }
}
```

Reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  posts: [],
  post: null,
  loading: true,
  error: {}
}

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action
  switch (type) {
    case UPDATE_COMMENT_LIKES:
      return {
        ...state,
        post: { ...state.post, comments: ???? }
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

It's passing in the post ID and the user ID, and then filtering based on whether or not they already exist.  I'll also add the action creators, just for clarity.

```
// Add like to comment
export const addCommentLike = id => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.put(`/api/posts/comment/like/${id}`)

    dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_COMMENT_LIKES,
      payload: { id, likes: res.data }
    })
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: POST_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status }
    })
  }
}

// Remove like from comment
export const removeCommentLike = id => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.put(`/api/posts/comment/unlike/${id}`)

    dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_COMMENT_LIKES,
      payload: { id, likes: res.data }
    })
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: POST_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status },
      loading: false
    })
  }
}
```

Right now, it's updating everything in the database, but it's not updating the state immediately and triggering a re-render.

I'd appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React redux - updating nested array in state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47458735/react-redux-updating-nested-array-in-state)

Comment: I highly recommend using a utility library to help you update nested state without mutating the initial state. Two options are [immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer) if you prefer a imperative style, or [ramda](https://ramdajs.com/) if you prefer functional style.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit too late but it might help for someone. I also did this course btw ;)
So in your case reducer would look like this:

```
case UPDATE_COMMENT_LIKES:
  return {
    ...state,
    post: {
      ...state.post,
      comments: state.post.comments.map((comment) =>
        comment._id === payload.id
          ? { ...comment, likes: payload.likes }
          : comment
      )
    },
    loading: false
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you'll split the remove/add logic in your reducer as well:

- `ADD_COMMENT_LIKES` - will add the like to the nested likes array
- `REMOVE_COMMENT_LIKES` - will filter the chosen like by its id

```
export default function(state = initialState, action) {

    const { type, payload } = action;

    switch (type) {
        case ADD_COMMENT_LIKES:
            return {
                ...state,
                post: {
                    ...state.post,
                    comments: [
                        ...state.post.comments,
                        likes: [
                            ...state.post.comments.likes,
                            payload <--- inserting the new like
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }
        case REMOVE_COMMENT_LIKES:
            return {
                ...state,
                post: {
                    ...state.post,
                    comments: [
                        ...state.post.comments,
                        likes: [
                            ...state.post.comments.likes.filter((item) => item.id !== payload.id)
                        ]
                    ]
                }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Read how to [combine reducers](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers), and form your state as a single independent branches. It will help you structure your reducer in a more maintainable structure.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm keeping the "UPDATE_COMMENT_LIKES" for now, but will work on changing it later (I'm still new to this, so every change takes ages).  When I try to do the likes: [ ...payload ] bit, it returns an error and says the "...payload" is an unexpected token.  Does it make a difference that "likes" is an array of objects, so it'd be accessed something like state.post.comments[0].likes...?

Comment: @PalmettoStater - it depends what you get as a response from the API. Try to inspect the value of  `res.data`.

Comment: I get back an object that looks like:  {
          _id: '5cebd8d1dc17fd5cd7e57a47',
          user: '5cd36ce5fda120050ee64160'
        }

Comment: The object you got is the updated (removed/added) like. This is the response object you got back from `axios` which signals that the update has been done successfully. Now, if you will use the reducer in my answer, it should join/filter the updated object as necessary.

Comment: In case you'll want to update a new version of that likes array without separated reducer logic for adding/removing as described in my answer, you will need another action and call an API to GET the comment data, and update this comment _likes_ array in the store.